# Install Android. v 4.0.4 on a STAR H3000+

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, installation

I've got mobile "STAR H3000+" (a rip off iPhone5) with Android v4.0.4.
I just wanted to ask if it is possible to install Android v4.2. or newer.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Bootloader unlocked? Rooted? Have you looked around XDA? :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Most Custom ROMS are developed by users in the XDA forums. Apparently there are no ROMS for Android 4.2.2 for this phone. 3rd party developer support for this phone seems to be rather poor. You won't be able to install Android 4.2.2.